# Finding the number of distinct maximal matching in a bipartite graph

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching, matching

In a bipartite graph, how can we find the total number of ways of getting a maximal matching?

The cardinality of both the sets in the bipartite graph may not be the same. So two matchings are said to be different if they have at least one distinct edge.

Comment: @Raphael - I think this question should be unmarked as duplicate. The question you've referred to has been recently put on hold as unclear, and it looks like its frustrated author has closed his/her account. Additionally, a similar question has been asked on SO recently, and I have given my answer, but this question has been put on hold as well. It looks like a war against the question! But actually it's a valid combinatorial question in case of complete bigraphs, and also a valid algorithmic question in case of general bigraphs.

Comment: @HEKTO I think this here question would be closed as unclear for the same reasons as the duplicate. The OP can improve their question at any time.

Comment: @Raphael - The question is formulated in such a way that it's evident the terminology is new to its author - but CS professionals can extract its real meaning, do they?

Comment: Apparently not. You may want to address your comments to those who closed that other question.

Comment: @Raphael - this other question is dead, its author is gone... However, the site says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer". It's not true because its only answer has been transformed into a comment by moderators. So you actually prevent answering the current question by referring it to a dead question without answers

Comment: @HEKTO So you would be happy if I unclosed this and closed it again as unclear? To me, that sounds like a waste of time. (Note how that question was closed as unclear *after* I closed this here as duplicate.) I consider this discussion to be over; I don't see a reason to open this question, nor to explain again why. If you have serious problems with that, please open a discussion on [meta].

Comment: Your question may or may not be the same as that earlier one… Both questions are unclear. They're clearly about the same topic — the number of maximal matchings in a bipartite graph — but what is your **question** on this topic? Have you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximal_matchings)?

Comment: @Gilles - the question  is "how can we find the total number of ways of getting a maximal matching". I've highlighted it and added a question mark in the end.

Comment: @Gilles - what is unclear *now*? The question is (and was) there, all the keywords and tags are there...

Comment: Are you interested in *maximal* or *maximum* (i.e. maximal *size*) matchings?

Comment: What research have you done?  Where have you looked?  What have you found so far on this topic?  On this site, we expect you to make a significant effort on your own before asking, and to tell us in the question what you've tried.  (Cc: @HEKTO.)